# Uninstall Android App Before Each Debug

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I am developing an Android app using Eclipse 3.7.2 with the Android SDK installed. I was wondering if there is a setting in Eclipse which when launching the debugger will automatically uninstall any previously existing versions of an app from the device?

For example, if I have an app developing, every time I make a change to the app I want to uninstall the old app completely from the phone and install the new one.

Comment: Interesting question. I don't know that this will work for sure however it seems you could use the build chain tool to do this for you. If you modify your build chain to run the adb command 'adb uninstall <packagename>' before compiling and installing happens you could get this effect. Someone likely has a more complete answer than this. Additionally this answer does not resolve the issue of multiple devices which would be a little more complicated.

Comment: not an answer, but with ant you just go "ant uninstall debug install"

Answer (score 47, accepted):

1. Right Click your Project
2. Properties
3. Builder
4. New
5. Program
6. In Name field, type "uninstall" for a name (no quotes needed)
7. In location, use Browse file system button and  target your adb (something like C:\Users\petey\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe)
8. In arguments, "uninstall your.app.package.goes.here"  (no quotes needed)
9. Hit OK
10. Select uninstall
11. Hit the Up button until its on the top

Now you should be able to debug & run your app and it will uninstall everytime.

If this is too much and yer on windows Keep a Run dialog open (Start key and r button at same time) and type "adb uninstall your.app.package.goes.here" (no quotes).  The run dialog has autocomplete and history to make life easier. You could also do this by terminal or command prompt too. Make sure that platform-tools is in your path tho.

Comment: When I try do it I get in console "Failure". I need

Comment: How to achieve this for multiple avds? I get an error "error: more than one device and emulator". I have an app installed in 5 avds.

Comment: @Naren  good question!  you will have to prefix #8 arguments with `-s <specific device>` where <specific device> is the given serial number or qualifier of the avd.  once this is done once, you can create/duplicate steps for an "uninstall" for each <specific device> identifier that you have