# Phonegap SQLite Error 23 Not Authorized

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, sqlite, cordova

### Resources:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#database_version

### Device/Framework Info:

- Nexus 4 - Android 4.2.2
- Phonegap 2.9.0
- Also using the bootstrap library for UI

I have followed the PhoneGap tutorial for version 2.9 on creating, and managing a database. So far I have found little to no places where people are talking about the specific error 23 when trying to write to a database.

I get this error after trying to write to a database after the insertBtn's click function, which executes the insertTemplate function.

The same thing happens when trying to delete a row when the deleteBtn event is fired, which executes the deleteTemplate function.

Any recommendations?

### Controller File:

```
var databaseName = "blackbriar";
var version = 1;
var displayName = "lctv";
var size = 2097152; // two megabytes
var db = null;

$(document).ready(function(event){
    // Gets shell for database
    db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDb, errorCb, successCb);
    db.transaction(loadTemplates, errorCb, successCb);

    $('#insertBtn').click(function(event){
        db.transaction(insertTemplate, errorCb, successCb);
    });

    $('#back').click(function(event){
        $('#templates').show();
        $('#templateEdit').hide();
        $('#back').hide();
    });
    $('#deleteBtn').click(function(event){
        db.transaction(deleteTemplate, errorCb, successCb);
        $('#back').click();
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.pill', function(event){
    // If window width is greater than 480px, isMobile variable is false
    var isMobile = $(window).width() > 480 ? false : true;

    $('#currentId').text($(this).attr('tempid'));
    db.transaction(getTemplateById, errorCb, successCb);

    if($('#currentId').text() == "-1"){
        $('#insertBtn').show();
        $('#saveBtn').hide();
        $('#deleteBtn').hide();
        $('#clearBtn').show();
    } else {
        $('#insertBtn').hide();
        $('#saveBtn').show();
        $('#deleteBtn').show();
        $('#clearBtn').hide();
    }

    // Checks if pill is active for UI changes
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        if(!isMobile){$(this).find('.temp').attr('style', 'color: black;');}
    } else {
        $('.pill').removeClass('active');
        $('.pill').find('.temp').attr('style', 'color: black;');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        if(!isMobile){$(this).find('.temp').attr('style', 'color: white;');}
    }
    if(isMobile) {
        $('#templates').hide();
        $('#templateEdit').show();
        $('#back').show();
    }
});
```

### My function file:

```
function getShell(databaseName, version, displayName, size) {
    return window.openDatabase(databaseName, version, displayName, size);
}

function populateDb(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS templates (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, templateName, description, campus, account, department, programName, projectId, taskId)');
}

function errorCb(error) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+error.code);
}

function successCb() {
    alert("Success!");
}

function insertTemplate(tx) {

    var templateName = $('#templateName').val();
    var description = $('#descriptionField').val();
    var campus = $('#campusField').val();
    var account = $('#accountField').val();
    var department = $('#departmentField').val();
    var programName = $('#programNameField').val();
    var projectId = $('#projectIdField').val();
    var taskId = $('#taskIdField').val();

    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO templates (templateName, description, campus, account, department, programName, projectId, taskId) VALUES ('
            +'"'+templateName+'"'+', '
            +'"'+description+'"'+', '
            +'"'+campus+'"'+', '
            +'"'+account+'"'+', '
            +'"'+department+'"'+', '
            +'"'+programName+'"'+', '
            +'"'+projectId+'"'+', '
            +'"'+taskId+'"'
            +')');
}

function loadTemplates(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * from templates', [], templatesSuccess, errorCb);
}

function templatesSuccess(tx, results) {
    var length = results.rows.length;
    $('#templateUl').html('');
    $('#templateUl').append('<li class="templi"><a class="pill" tempid="-1"><text class="temp"><i style="color: green;" class="icon-plus"></i> Create</text></a></li>');
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        $('#templateUl').append('<li class="templi"><a class="pill" tempid="'+results.rows.item(i).id+'"><text class="temp">'+results.rows.item(i).templateName+'</text></a></li>');
    }
}

function getTemplateById(tx) {
    var currentId = $('#currentId').text();
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM templates WHERE id = '+currentId, [], loadTemplateSuccess, errorCb);
}

function loadTemplateSuccess(tx, results) {
    if(results.rows.length > 0){
        var template = results.rows.item(0);
        var templateName = $('#templateName').val(template.templateName);
        var description = $('#descriptionField').val(template.description);
        var campus = $('#campusField').val(template.campus);
        var account = $('#accountField').val(template.account);
        var department = $('#departmentField').val(template.department);
        var programName = $('#programNameField').val(template.programName);
        var projectId = $('#projectIdField').val(template.projectId);
        var taskId = $('#taskIdField').val(template.taskId);
    } else {
        var templateName = $('#templateName').val('');
        var description = $('#descriptionField').val('');
        var campus = $('#campusField').val('');
        var account = $('#accountField').val('');
        var department = $('#departmentField').val('');
        var programName = $('#programNameField').val('');
        var projectId = $('#projectIdField').val('');
        var taskId = $('#taskIdField').val('');
    }
}

function deleteTemplate(tx) {
    var currentId = $('#currentId').text();
    alert(currentId);
    tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM templates', [], templatesSuccess, errorCb);
    alert("Authorize!!!");
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what to suggest to workaround this but it looks like PhoneGap is trying to use Android's native implementation of WebSQL - Read about this specific issue you are having here - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2639

Comment: @Ross It says that issue was resolved, and that it happened in 2.2

Comment: Yeah I believe it was marked as resolved because it could not be reproduced.  It certainly doesn't appear to be resolved because you're using the latest version of PhoneGap.  Sorry I'm not trying to indicate it is or isn't resolved, I'm just trying to help you investigate the issue and gather some info to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Just came into this, i had to uninstall the app and re made it (Also changed the version but i dont think that did it).
Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105674/uninstall-android-app-before-each-debug) so i uninstall the app everytime i debug. This can be annoying if you have to insert items each time, but atleast solved it.

Comment: can you please explain me what te real cause is?, I have tried the given link, but not working for me,

Comment: This is my theory. Turns out that when you re install an application the local data is not cleared. Then if you clear it after you create your database, it actually wont exists, thats why this works. The problem itself was a bug and its suposed not to be there anymore. Unless of course if you are trying to access a different version of the database. Sorry i dont know anymore.