# Canvas signature touch creates issue in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, jquery-mobile, cordova

I found a few posts related to "phonegap canvas signature" but they did not help. I have some drop down boxes, text boxes, and one signature field. I want to insert these fields in sqlite Database.

My database table creation looks like this:

```
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parts(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,nr,productId,description,toolsVerified)");
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS costs(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,nr,date,starttime,endtime,reason,cost)");
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sign(orderNr unique ,rapport,sign)");
```

Read the field values like normal for text and dropdown for canvas signature field is like

```
kundusSign = $("#mKundusskirt")[0];
kundensUnderSkrift = kundusSign.toDataURL();
```

Here is the code for insert data:

```
db
    .transaction(function(tx) {
        // for parts table
        tx
                .executeSql(
                        "insert into parts(nr,productid,description,toolsVerified) values(?,?,?,?)",
                        [ nr, productId, desc, tool ]);
        // for cost table
        tx
                .executeSql(
                        "insert into costs(nr,date,starttime,endtime,reason,cost) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                        [ nr, date, startTime, endTime, reason, cost ]);

        // for sign table
        signQuery = 'UNION SELECT ' + nr + ", '" + rapport + "','"
                + kundensUnderSkrift + "'";
        tx
                .executeSql('insert or replace into "sign" SELECT "orderNr","rapport","sign"'
                        + signQuery);
    });
```

I included [sign plugin](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/#require-drawn) for signatures. Now my problem is that when I type in the signature field, the database fields are not inserted. Also when I try to remove the sign insert query and put sign means the other two table (cost and parts) values are also not inserted. If I didn't touch the sign fields, all values are inserted successfully for image the inserts the toDataurl() format.

I only got this error in stack trace:

`sqlite (23) not authorised`.

Please give some solution to this.

EDIT:
I also tried this:

```
tx.executeSql("insert into sign(orderNr,sign,rapport)values(?,?,?)",[nr,rapport,kundensUnderSkrift]);
```

Comment: Maybe this question helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/17550272/1741542

Answer (score 1):

Well, it can be from many places.

1st of all are you testing it on Android (2.3 or lower)? If so than the problem is most probably that `.toDataUrl()` is not supported by Android default browser which means it will not work in PhoneGap either.

So first think I suggest you to do is to double check that you really have a string in kundensUnderSkrift.

2nd sometimes WebSql can be tricky I will so to be on the safe side I will use this to create the table:

```
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sign(orderNr unique ,rapport,sign STRING)");
```

WebSql updates do not seem to work at all, so make sure you clear data or uninstall up, than give it another go.

3rd Your statement order look wrong:

```
tx.executeSql("insert into sign(orderNr,sign,rapport)values(?,?,?)",[nr,rapport,kundensUnderSkrift]);
```

Should be:

```
tx.executeSql("insert into sign(orderNr,rapport,sign)values(?,?,?)",[nr,rapport,kundensUnderSkrift]);
```

If after checking all 3 points it's still not working, I will suggest to try the following UGLY approach:

```
tx.executeSql("insert into sign(orderNr,sign,rapport) values('"+nr+"','"+ kundensUnderSkrift+"','"+rapport+"');",[],function(tx,success){alert("ALL OK");},function(tx,error){alert(error.message);});
```

You can use console.log instead of alert but on mobile's I find it a lot easier to do debug with alert. (except windows phone, where alert is not supported by default).

Comment: i am using latest **android version not 2.3** and also **insert or replace** query works fine in my another page and also **kundensUnderSkrift** returns string value only. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You really should be passing error callbacks to `transaction()` and `executeSql()` methods - it'll help debugging your database operations in development.  You'll want to use something other than `alert()` for error handling in production.

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    // for parts table
    tx.executeSql(
        "insert into parts(nr,productid,description,toolsVerified) values(?,?,?,?)",
        [ nr, productId, desc, tool ],
        null, sqlError
    );

    // for cost table
    tx.executeSql(
        "insert into costs(nr,date,starttime,endtime,reason,cost) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)",
        [ nr, date, startTime, endTime, reason, cost ],
        null, sqlError
    );

    // for sign table
    tx.executeSql(
        'insert or replace into sign(orderNr,rapport,sign) values (?,?,?)'
        [nr, rapport, kundensUnderSkrift],
        null, sqlError
        );
}, xactError);

function sqlError(tx, err) {
    alert("Statement failed: " + err.message);
}

function xactError(err) {
    alert("Transaction failed: " + err.message);
}
```

Comment: i solved my issue...error handling is not an issue. thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: What ended up causing the problem?  You can add an answer to your question and then mark it as accepted.

Comment: Signature takes too much time to read. After inserted load new page so it creates error. So i wrote setTimeout function to redirect page.