# Android - Eclipse not deploying new build

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've got this problem that after **I do changes to My code and Run the project**, I get this always in the console.

```
Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
Starting activity authentication.LoginActivity on device nexus4testdev
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.myapp/authentication.LoginActivity }
ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

Previously it used to uninstall old app and install the new one onto the device.Now it throws this in the console every time.

After doing some research I found out that `Java Builder` has to enabled to resolve this problem. However I disabled `Java Builder` in the first place because I was getting `The Type R is already defined` error. It all started all of a sudden. Now I cannot deploy My app without manually uninstalling the app from the device which is a big headache. Any help appreciated.

Edit: Now I saw the bin folder and noticed that the *.apk is never built.

Comment: Your error `Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front` shows that in your emulator your application is already running and you are again trying to run it. First of all just close the application and then again try to run it. Or it may be running in background so from your settings first just forceclose it and then again install it, it should work.

Comment: I think your new code is not being built as you have disabled the Java builder. Can you please tell why exactly you disabled it? The error for `R` is usually shown when you have imported android.R in your project.

Comment: It used to work before without closing the application. When I run, eclipse will do the uninstall and reinstall. Now it's not doing.

Comment: @Swayam, I disabled the Java Builder because in the gen folder I was getting type R is already defined error for one of the library I'm using. After disabling Java Builder the error is resolved but eclipse doesn't create a new build.

Comment: @PsyGik Check out my answer. No need to disable java builder for this.

Comment: @PsyGik : I really don't think that you should be disabling the Builder. Like I said, your project is not getting built. I suggest you put it back on and find other ways to fix the error, like cleaning and fixing dependencies.

Comment: @Swayam, yes even I'm thinking the same, but if I enable the builder then that Type R error pops up.

Comment: @PsyGik Can you ask a new question about the errors?

Answer (score 0):

Your error `Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front` shows that in your emulator your application is already running and you are again trying to run it.

First of all just close the application and then again try to run it. Or it may be running in background so from your settings first just `forceclose` it and then again install it, it should work.

It will always run application without closing if you did make any changes in your application after once installation. If you do not make any changes and then try to run application without closing it in that case it will show such kind of errors.

*Once try to clean and Build your project and then run it again.*

Comment: Of course I made changes to the code and then did Run.Please read the first sentence of my question.

Comment: What such changes you did so it doesn't allowing you to re-install now ? Have you tried uninstalling old and installing again ?

Comment: Manually if I uninstall from device then it works. But eclipse doesn't uninstall on it's own,which is not the expected behavior. Changes to the code: I added a couple of new methods and variables.

Comment: It happens sometimes because of the device storage also.

Comment: I'm using a Nexus 4 16gig with 12gig free. I doubt this has anything to do with the storage.

Comment: Have you build your project again and cleaned it after making changes ?

Comment: Yes and Yes. Still the same.

Comment: Maybe, I'll recheck everything again.

Answer (score 0):

For some types of changes, Eclipse does not rebuild the APK file. In situation like these, you need to do Project -> Clean to force a rebuild.

Comment: Done that, doesn't work unless I manually uninstall application from the device. Eclipse should do the uninstall when I Run after making changes to the code. That is the expected behavior right?!

Comment: @PsyGik What kind of code changes are you making? Are you changing Java code? Or are you changing the manifest or resource files?

Comment: Java changes. I wrote a couple of new methods and variables.

Comment: @PsyGik Did you make the changes inside Eclipse or did you use an external editor? Did you save the files? Do you have multiple projects open in Eclipse? If so, double check that you are running the project where you made the changes. Excuse me if these questions seem basic. I am just trying to think of all the reasons that you might see this behavior.

Comment: Yes I did all of that. Doesn't matter if it's basic or advanced. We're developers and we should always check basics too, because that's what we always ignore. If it helps, it's the actionbar-pull-to-refresh library that causes Type R error, for which I disabled Java Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Usually what I do instead of cleaning my build is force a change. I take any java class, add a space, remove it, and save. This tricks Eclipse into recompiling the code for you, which will allow you to upload the new software to the device.

Comment: Which is exactly what I do always, but in this instance it doesn't build the *.apk.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does NOT uninstall any existing app of the same name before deploying it again.  Even if you make code changes, and then clean/compile, then deploy to your device or emulator, there is no guarantee that everything is gone from the device.

This is especially true if you have created any files, such as SharedPreferences or SQLite databases, since the last time you uninstalled.

This is why I always keep a terminal window open with:

```
adb uninstall my.app.name
```

Mapped to an alias called 'u'.  I can uninstall it quickly and then redeploy.  This can be automated, there is a great writeup on how to do that here:

[Uninstall Android App Before Each Debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105674/uninstall-android-app-before-each-debug)

Good luck.

Comment: I'd disagree on your point that eclipse does not uninstall. It does uninstall the app when I redeploy after making code changes. It always has, but yes the data in SharedPreferences and SQLite DB are not wiped, which I don't need to be cleaned either. And your suggestion of manually doing the uninstall is good, but my problem is that, eclipse doesn't build the *.apk if it's existing on the device. This is not the expected behavior since Eclipse should do the uninstall and reinstall on its own.

Comment: Eclipse does not uninstall the app.  There is only one definition of the term uninstall, by which I mean remove an application and all its artifacts from the filesystem.  Eclipse does not do this.  It installs your app into the same location it has already been installed, overwriting any files in the process.  But things left behind, such as SharedPreferences and databases, are NOT removed.  Eclipse does not run 'adb uninstall appname' in between deployments.

Comment: Speaking in that sense you're right. But here in my case, eclipse does not install the app when I run the project unless I manually uninstall the app from the device. I tested a different project and that one works perfectly fine.