# Android-ActionBar-PullToRefresh-Type R is already defined error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file, pull-to-refresh

I'm currently facing this issue when I add [ActionBar-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh) library in Eclipse. The error I get is `The Type R is already defined`.

Steps how I added the library:

1. Got all files from git.
2. Since I'm targeting Android 2.3.* I need `appcompat` library too. So    I've imported `actionbarcompat` from the extras folder.
3. Next I imported the `library`. The `library` is dependent on    `SmoothProgressBar`, so I imported that too.
4. The `actionbarcompat` which I imported in step 2 needed the library    (Step 3) and `support-v7-appcompat` library. I added both as    dependency.
5. Next in My Project I added `actionbarcompat` as a dependency and    cleaned project.

This is when I started getting the error. In the gen folder I've the R.java for the following libraries:

```
android.support.v7.appcompat
fr.castorflex.android.smoothprogressbar
uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras.actionbarcompat
uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library
```

I'm facing the error in R.java of  uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library. Did I go wrong in adding any of the libraries?

P.S: I can resolve this error by disabling Java Builder but by doing that I'm getting a new problem for which I've raised another question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449252/android-eclipse-not-deploying-new-build/21449398?noredirect=1#comment32367540_21449398) (I asked that question first, then one of the members asked me to raise question for this issue as well).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: delete the build files and compile the project again! hope that will help

Comment: Done that.Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

this error seems to appear because u might be building a library more than once , check this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5283488) I hope this will help

Comment: Yes, I've looked at that answer. I've written the same in Post Script